# How to extract value of z alpha/2 from a dictionary for finding interval estimate?

Tags: python, statistics, intervals

```
def estimates(sample_size,Sample_mean,sd,CI=0.95):
    zdict={'0.05':'1.68', '0.025':' 1.96'}
    tdict={'0.05':'1.746', '0.025':' 2.120'}

    select=input("What do you want to do : ")
    if select=='1':
        xbar=Sample_mean
        print("PointEstimateCalc: ",xbar)
    elif select=='2':
        if sample_size>=30:
            xbar=Sample_mean
            zalpha=1-CI
            a=zalpha/2
            if a in zdict:
                zdict[a].estimates()
```

*** The variable 'a' holds a value which matches with one key in zdict. Now i dont know how to match the variable with the key and get the value so that i can calculate interval estimate ***

```
                interval_estimate=(xbar)+(zdict[a].estimates()*sd)/math.sqrt(sample_size)
```

Comment: be very wary of using floats as dict keys.  They aren't what you necessarily expect `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` for example

Comment: can you please explain how can i resolve it . I am new to coding stuff .

Comment: redesign your program so you're always looking up integers, or use rounding when calculating your `a`